# Генерация поддомена

Tags: php, веб-программирование, домен, поддомены

Нужно сгенерировать поддомен при нажатии на кнопку (`случайный-поддомен.site.com`). Вот генератор строки:

```
function rand_string(
    $length = 8,
    $repeat = false,
    $UpperCase = true,
    $LowerCase = true,
    $Symbols = true,
    $SymbolsList__ = '0123456789-',
    $UpperCaseList = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    $LowerCaseList = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
{
    if ($UpperCase) {
        $UpperCase = $UpperCaseList;
    }

    if ($LowerCase) {
        $LowerCase = $LowerCaseList;
    }

    if ($Symbols) {
        $Symbols = $SymbolsList__;
    }

    unset($UpperCaseList, $LowerCaseList, $SymbolsList__);
    switch (rand(0, 5)) {
    case 0:
        $All = $UpperCase . $LowerCase . $Symbols;
    case 1:
        $All = $UpperCase . $Symbols . $LowerCase;
    case 2:
        $All = $Symbols . $LowerCase . $UpperCase;
    case 3:
        $All = $Symbols . $UpperCase . $LowerCase;
    case 4:
        $All = $LowerCase . $Symbols . $UpperCase;
    case 5:
        $All = $LowerCase . $UpperCase . $Symbols;
    }

    unset($UpperCase, $LowerCase, $Symbols);
    $totalLength = strlen($All) - 1;
    if (!$repeat) {
        $totalLength++;
        if ($length > $totalLength) {

            //       echo "Error while generating the string: the maximum length is exceeded ($length instead of $totalLength characters)";

            return false;
        }

        $totalLength--;
        while ($i++ < $length) {
            $Current = $All{rand(0, $totalLength--) };
            $All = str_replace($Current, '', $All);
            $string.= $Current;
        }
    }
    else {
        while ($i++ < $length) {
            $string.= $All{rand(0, $totalLength) };
        }
    }

    unset($All, $i, $length, $totalLength, $repeat);
    return $string;
}

echo rand_string()
```

Допустим сгенерировано значение `lhtjnz23`. Как это  значение присвоить к домену `.site.com` чтобы было `lhtjnz23.site.com`?

Comment: уточните вопрос - что Вы хотите сделать?

Answer (score 2):

**htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     Options +FollowSymlinks 
     RewriteBase /

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
     RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

**index.php**:

```
$params = array(); 
$t = explode(".", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]); 
$subdomain = $t[0];
echo "You asked me subdomain: '$subdomain'";
```

Итого имеем:

1. сервер с включенным модулем mod_rewrite
2. файл .htaccess с переопределением запроса
3. файл index.php, предназначенный для обработки **всех** запросов к сайту

А уж как сделать маршрутизацию и т.д. и т.п. думайте сами

Источники:

1. [phpinfo.su. ЧПУ на PHP](http://www.phpinfo.su/articles/practice/chpu_na_php.html)
2. Собственная голова с небольшими познаниями PHP

Comment: у меня при запросе classes.localhost браузер выдал сообщение You asked me subdomain 'classes' =)

Answer (score -1):

Как я понял вам надо разбиться с так называемым **ЧПУ** (Человеко-Понятными УРЛ). В качестве примера можете посмотреть статью http://www.phpinfo.su/articles/practice/chpu_na_php.html

В данной статье рассматривается работа в частности с URI. Рам же надо всего лишь добиться разделения названия сайта на поддомен.домен.зона используя команду explode по символу "."

Comment: Мне надо из  rand_string() вставить в "subdomain".site.com   subdomain- сгенерированное генератором

Comment: после генерации использовать header?

Comment: Например, **header("Location: http:\\".rand_string.".domain.com\");
Я правильно вас понял? и уже потом все обработать как ЧПУ?

Сейчас все попробую, сообщу о результатах